# Python3 : Do dict constructor create deep copies?

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-copy

I'm trying to understand shallow-copy vs deep-copy concept in Python3.

From below code I found that change done in dict2 is not getting reflected back in dict1.

```
1>>> dict1 = {1:[1,2]}
2>>> dict2 = dict(dict1)
3>>> dict2[1]=[1,2,3]
4>>> dict1,dict2
({1: [1, 2]}, {1: [1, 2, 3]})
```

Am I correct in understanding that a deep copy is created on line#2 in above code.

Comment: No. You're just assigning a new value to key 1. It doesn't need to be deep cloned for that to not affect the other dict.

Comment: Makes sense , thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`dict` "constructor"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) can accept a "mapping object", in which case it creates a new dictionary initialized from a mapping object's (key, value) pairs.

This is what happens here, as `dict1` is a mapping object.

This is however NOT a deep copy, take a look at this example:

```py
>>> dict1 = {1:[1,2]}
>>> dict2 = dict(dict1)
>>> dict1,dict2
({1: [1, 2]}, {1: [1, 2]})
>>> dict1[1].append(4)
>>> dict1,dict2
({1: [1, 2, 4]}, {1: [1, 2, 4]})
>>>
```

you see how both `dict1` and `dict2` changed even though I changed just `dict1`? that's because they both point to the same list.

In your example, you replaced `dict2`'s list with a new list, and what this demonstrates is the new dict is indeed a copy and not just a ref to the original dict.

To put it simply: the dictionary itself is "copied", but the inner values held in it are not.